# socket.io broadcasting too many packets

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to broadcast a simple price updated for a products to all connected clients.
It works. Meaning that the broadcast is successful and I can update my values, but what is broadcasted is the problem.

Socket.io broadcast ALL the message since the start of the server, instead of just sending the last one. I can't seem to find how to limit the broadcast to the latest updated price.

Server:

```
// Broadcast new price
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('bidAction', function(from, msg){
    socket.broadcast.emit('bid', { price: new_price, product_id: productID });
  });
});
```

Client:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
socket.on('bid', function (data) {
  console.log(data);

  // We get the element with price
  $('span.price').html(data.price.toFixed(2)) ;
});

// Now when the price is changed
$('.bid').click(function(){
  // We emit the bidding
  socket.emit('bidAction', {data: 'stuff'});
});
```

Comment: Is the code given on client being called again? This happens when you create new connection several times, the connect is fired multiple times.

Comment: no the click event is on an input[type=button], called once

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you did this on purpose or by mistake.Right now you have a

```
function(from, msg)
```

and trying to broadcast

```
price: new_price, product_id: productID
```

new_price and productID are both **undefined** in your example.

Could you please change your code to the following so that it makes more sense?

Client Side:

```
socket.emit('bidAction', {new_price: 'stuff' , productID : 'stuff'});
```

Server Side:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('bidAction', function(data){
    socket.broadcast.emit('bid', { price: data.new_price, product_id: data.productID });
  });
});
```